# Can a relationship be constructed between the Coherence space and Phase space semantics of linear logic?

Tags: linear-logic

I'm not very familiar with linear logic, so please bear with me, i.e., please "read between the lines" to my underlying question if I don't formulate it rigorously correctly.

To help model some of my own stuff, I'm trying to impose a coherence-like relation on the phase space monoid. So, generally speaking, I want to construct a coherence space that can be associated with a corresponding phase space. But first of all, it seems to me a coherence space more properly corresponds to a phase space fact, i.e., a subset $A\subseteq M$ where $A^{\perp\perp}=A$. So each such fact would have a coherence space, somehow to be matched at the boundaries/overlaps with all other facts. Or something along those lines.

I couldn't google anything about this kind of construction, but figure if it makes any sense at all, then somebody(s) must have already written about it. Can you guys point me to any relevant literature? Or if it makes no sense (more than a little likely, I suppose:), explain why not/what I'm goofed up about/etc.

Thanks,
John